# Hibernate, parent/child confusion

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I have a simple object relation, I wish to persist with hibernate.

Basically, its a Parent which contains a collection of Children. All I wish to do, is load the parent if it exists, otherwise create it, add elements to it and save it.

This is being done in a GWT enviroment, so I pass a ChildDTO to this method, which is basically just a non-persistant version of the Child class (which is incompatible with gwts RPC serialization).

```
public Integer testHibernate(Integer parentId, ChildDTO[] test) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    Parent model;
    if(parentId == null) {
        // if the parentId is null, create new instance 
        model = new Parent ); 
    }
    else {
        model = (Parent) hib.load(Parent.class, dto.getId());
    }

    model.setName("dummy name");

    for(int i = 0; i < test.length) {
        model.addChild(new Child(test[i].getId(), test[i].getName()));
    }

    hib.save(model);        
    hib.getTransaction().commit();

    return model.getId();
}
```

Right, this works fine for creating new Parents, without children. It also works fine if i am just adding one child to an existing parent. However, if i add more than one child, i get a "could not insert" error from hibernate.

Also, if I try adding just one child, to a already existing parent, which already have one child added. I get a "a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session" error.

Additional question. When inserting just one child, on a empty parent, hibernate does the following:

```
Hibernate: insert into Child(ChildId, ChildName) values (default, ?)
Hibernate: update Parent set ChildId=? where ChildId=?
```

Whats with the update? :S

Comment: Please provide the stack trace. Also, show the source for the parent/child relationship showing how you set up the One-To-Many relationship. My guess is that the One-To-Many is set up incorrectly in either your DB or objects.

Comment: Can you show hibernate mapping for Parent and Child. Also show Parent class specifically what addChild does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **However, if i add more than one child, i get a "could not insert"
>   error from hibernate**.

From the question *it seems* that the Parent-Child relationship has been setup as one-to-one rather than one-to-many. First make sure that is correct in your hibernate config file.

```
<set name="children">
    <key column="parent_id"/>
    <one-to-many class="Child"/>
</set>
```

> **Also, if I try adding just one child, to a already existing parent,
>   which already have one child added. I get a "a different object with
>   the same identifier value was already associated with the session"
>   error.**

In the following code snippet, you just save the child with the Id without checking if it already exists. Remember that `Child` is also stored in database as a row. So you need to check if that object exists in database.

```
for(int i = 0; i < test.length) {
        model.addChild(new Child(test[i].getId(), test[i].getName()));
    }
```

> **When inserting just one child, on a empty parent, hibernate does the
>   following:**

That is logical, the first `INSERT` statement corresponds to the new row for the `Child` object. The second `UPDATE` statement corresponds to establishing the link between `Parent` and `Child` objects.

You could optimize this by setting up `inverse` relation. In this scenario, the `Child` table stores the parent_id and therefore results in one `INSERT` statement than two statements.

```
<set name="children" inverse="true">
    <key column="parent_id"/>
    <one-to-many class="Child"/>
</set>
```

---

Refer to this link in Hibernate documentation which clearly explains on how to setup and implement the `Parent-Child` relationship: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/example-parentchild.html#example-parentchild-bidir

Comment: you are a star sir. The for loop was a bit embarrassing, I suppose that one was a case of me not to be able to find the forest because I couldn't see past all the trees :P (i mean, i was already handling this for the parent, good knows why i thought it was needed for the children). You where spot on about the relationship being wrong, I was mapping using OneToMany and JoinColumn annotations, but i was using the childId so i think it was trying to update the primary key of the Children table lol. Thanks alot! I would give you two pluses if i could :D